# how not to create unit test file in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
rails g model GiftProduct -p --migration=false --fixture=false
```

i tried this code,and it reduce some generate file but still can't find how to avoid unit test file genertate,

in fact i only want a model file

i'm new on rail3,hope someone could help me
below is the generate result

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    app/models/gift_product.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/gift_product_test.rb
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try setting the test framework to `nil` or any non-existent test framework.

```
rails g model Test -t nil
```

Outputs

```
invoke  active_record
create    db/migrate/20101102025557_create_tests.rb
create    app/models/test.rb
 error    nil [not found]
```

Admittedly, not the nicest or most correct way of doing it, but it works.

Comment: is there some place that has many rails developer can communicate,i found irc is useless,

Comment: Using forums like these is probably your best bet, unless you know any one personally who does Rails development. But you're in luck, because Stackoverflow just implemented chat rooms and there's one for Ruby/Rails, though I haven't used it myself. Check it out here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24/ruby-rails. Feel free to continue to asking questions on Stackoverflow. From my experience, people are quick to respond and really helpful. It sucks not having an answer right away, but I'm almost always confident that I'll eventually get help from someone on here.

Answer (score 25):

Works in Rails 3.2:

```
rails g model Foo --no-test-framework
```

Comment: this should be the selected answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
rails g model project  --no-tests --no-fixtures --no-migrations
```

I'm not only R3 yest so I'm not sure

Comment: sorry :(, like I said, I'm not on R3 yet. You can always remove the fies once they are created.